# Sufficient condition for existence of repeated limits and double limit (Moore-Osgood theorem)

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

From Wikipedia ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_limit#:~:text=does%20not%20exist.-,Sufficient%20condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_limit#:%7E:text=does%20not%20exist.-,Sufficient%20condition))

> If ${\displaystyle \lim _{x\to p}f(x,y)}$ exists pointwise for each y
> different from q and if ${\displaystyle \lim _{y\to q}f(x,y)}$
> converges uniformly for $x \neq p$ then the double limit and the
> iterated limits exist and are equal.

Now I tried to check this theorem for $$f(x,y) = \dfrac{x^2y^2}{x^2y^2+(x-y)^2}, \,\,(p,q)=(0,0)$$
First of all we can see that the repeated limits do exist on point (0,0) and they are both equal to 0 and we can show that the double limit on (0,0) doesn't exist. In fact $f(x,x)\rightarrow1$ but $f(x,-x) \rightarrow 0$ on point $x=0$. Consequently the limit of $f(x,y)$ doesn't exist. Now this would mean that the above theorem's conditions shouldn't be fulfilled for this function. The first condition is fulfilled, because $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}{\dfrac{x^2y^2}{x^2y^2+(x-y)^2}} = \dfrac{0}{y^2} = 0 (\forall y \neq 0)$. The same way we can see that $\lim_{y\rightarrow0}{\dfrac{x^2y^2}{x^2y^2+(x-y)^2}} = 0$ too. But this would mean that the second condition is fulfilled as well. But this is a contradiction. So is this theorem a special case or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: In your example, the convergence is not uniform: since $f(x, x) = 1$, it's impossible to choose $\delta > 0$ independent of $y$ s.t. $|f(x, y)| < 1/2$ for all $x$ s.t. $|x| < \delta$. However, we can construct an example where the convergence is uniform (even without the conditions $x \neq p$, $y \neq q$) but the double limit does not exist; the condition missing from the Wikipedia article is that if the domain of $f$ is $X \times Y$, we require $p \in \overline X \setminus X$ and $q \in \overline Y \setminus Y$.